# Lectures on triangulations of manifolds by Robion Kirby

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I was looking for the book mentioned in the title. Seemingly it was not published, but copies are available in several mathematical libraries. Google books does not provide preview.

I am wondering if someone could provide the table of contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the table of contents. It seems to me most if not all of this material is in Kirby-Siebenmann.

[image: Table of contents]

Comment: Thank you for providing the content. I noticed that there is no page number indicated for section 0, 7 and the appendix. Could you let me know how many pages are included for those sections? Thanks.

Comment: There are 110 pages in total, Chapter 7 starts on page 98, and this copy has no(!) appendix.

Comment: Thank you very much.